# Javascript return results from an external PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, openstreetmap

This is probably really simple but I'm suffering from brain fade ...

I have a piece of Javascript code that sets an *"addressPoints"* variable to JSON formatted information, like so (two different places, with lat/lng);

```
var addressPoints = [{"lat":"50.821980","lng":"-3.819536","place":"Zeal Monachorum"},{"lat":"51.118729","lng":"-4.020714","place":"Youlston"}];
```

... but instead of manually feeding this variable the information, I have a PHP file called *"getMarkers.php"* that works & generates a longer list of information formatted in exactly the same way that I would like to use instead ...

My question is, how do I set the contents of the Javascript variable *"addressPoints"* to the results returned from the *"getMarkers.php"* file?

Answer (score -1):

You could also create a  tag, then store what is returned by the PHP variable within the

tag and call its value with the 'whatever' id in JS :)

In your PHP:

```html
<p id="whatever" style="display:none;">'.$variable.'</p>
```

In your JS:

```javascript
var newVar = $('#whatever').val;
```

Or something like that :) Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I've currently solved my issue using the following code;

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getMarkers.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        addressPoints = data;
    }
});
```

Which feels somewhat of a hack turning off async, but it works ... is this the best way?

Answer (score -2):

Try use e.g. JQuery Ajax :)

This should look like this

```
$.getJSON("www.example.com/getMarkers.php", function(result) {
   addressPoints = result;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work (obviously having removed the www.example.com)

Comment: That code should work, but maybe you're getting bitten by the fact it's async code. That is, you're probably doing stuff with `addressPoints` before the AJAX call completes.

Comment: Is there a way to get around the async problem? Can sync be forced .. or some other solution?